# How to count number string that read the same in forward and backward

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, palindrome

Suppose there is a number string that have 10 digit and I want find how many combination that read the same in forward and backward

I have tried 10x9x8x7x6 but it that the case for distinct case like 9876556789?

this is obvious miscount the case like 3333333333

What is the official to find the combination

Comment: You only need to choose the first 5 digits (the last 5 digits will automatically be determined due to the palindrome condition).

Comment: Yes, you are over-thinking this. It's simply $10^5$.